# Definition of Quotient Spaces from Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology

Lee in Introduction to Topological Manifolds says that given an equivalence relation $\sim$ on a topological space $X$, the set of equivalence classes wrt $\sim$, together with the quotient topology induced by the canonical quotient map $x\mapsto [x]_\sim$, is the quotient space wrt $\sim$.

I have been wondering, given a quotient map $q:X\to Y$, is it consistent with the above definition to call $Y$ with the quotient topology induced by $q$ as a quotient space?

Following an argument on Wikipedia for the entry on quotient spaces, I can show that given a quotient map $q:X\to Y$ we can consider $X/\sim$ to be the set of fibers of $q$ and there exists a homeomorphism $X/\sim\to Y$, $[x]_\sim\mapsto q(x)$. So does this already answer my question i.e. can $Y$ with the quotient topology induced by the quotient map $q:X\to Y$ be considered a quotient space?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: yes, you have answered your own question. in this situation, $Y$ is indeed a quotient space, homeomorphic to $X/\sim$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quotient map is a surjective function $q : X \to Y$ such that a subset $U \subset Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $q^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Note that quotient maps are continuous (this is the "only if" part of the definition).

In this definition we deal with two *topological spaces* $X,Y$.

In contrast Lee considers a *topological space* $X$ with an equivalence  relation $\sim$ and forms the *set* $Y = X/{\sim}$ of equivalence classes with respect to $\sim$. There is of course a canonical surjective *quotient function* $q : X \to Y$, but the set $Y$ does not yet have a topology.

More generally, given any surjection $q : X \to Y$ from a topological space $X$ to a set $Y$, we can give $Y$ the finest topology such that $q$ becomes continuous. This topology is known as the *quotient topology on $Y$ induced by $q$*. Explicitly it is given by
$$\mathcal T_q = \{ U \subset Y \mid q^{-1}(U) \text{ is open in } X \} .$$
The topological space $(Y,\mathcal T_q)$ is called the *quotient space of $X$ by $q$*.

Thus, if we endow $Y$ with the quotient topology, then $q$ becomes a quotient map in the sense of the above definition.

Lee's $q_\sim: X \to X/{\sim}$ is just a special case of this construction:  The quotient set $X/{\sim}$  will automatically be endowed with the quotient topology. This makes $q_\sim$ a quotient map.

As you say, given any quotient map $q : X \to Y$, one obtains an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ by setting $x \sim x'$ iff $q(x) = q(x')$. Then in fact there exists a unique homeomorphism $h : Y \to X/{\sim }$ such that $h \circ q = q_\sim$.

In other words, up to homeomorphism there are no other quotient maps than the special $q_\sim$.

Comment: Extremely clear, thank you very much :))